# SQL query assistance

Tags: sql

I have this schema:

```
Hotel (**hotelNo**, hotelName, city)
Room (**roomNo, hotelNo**, type, price)
Booking (**hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom**, dateTo, roomNo)
Guest (**guestNo**, guestName, guestAddress)
** denotes primary keys
```

I have to complete this query:

- Display each hotel and its most common room.

I have this query, which isn't quite correct:

```
SELECT r.hotelno, type, count(*)
FROM Hotel h, room r
WHERE h.hotelNo = r.hotelno
GROUP BY r.hotelNo, type;
```

This is what it outputs:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you're seeking the type of room which has maximum number of bookings for rooms of a given type at each hotel - an aggregate (maximum) of another aggregate (count of bookings of room type).

Build it up piece-wise.  The number of bookings of rooms of each type at each hotel:

```
SELECT r.hotelno, r.type, count(*) AS num_bookings
  FROM Booking AS b
  JOIN Room AS r ON b.hotelNo = r.hotelno AND b.roomNo = r.roomNo
 GROUP BY r.hotelNo, r.type;
```

Now, you need to know which room type has the maximum at each hotel.  That has to be done in two stages:

1. Find the maximum number of bookings at the hotel for any type.
2. Find the room types with that maximum number.

The first stage is:

```
SELECT s.hotelno, MAX(num_bookings) AS max_bookings
  FROM (SELECT r.hotelno, r.type, count(*) AS num_bookings
          FROM Booking AS b
          JOIN Room AS r ON b.hotelNo = r.hotelno AND b.roomNo = r.roomNo
         GROUP BY r.hotelNo, r.type
       ) AS s
 GROUP BY s.hotelno;
```

The second stage uses both the previous results for a final answer:

```
SELECT t.hotelno, t.type
  FROM (SELECT r.hotelno, r.type, count(*) AS num_bookings
          FROM Booking AS b
          JOIN Room AS r ON b.hotelNo = r.hotelno AND b.roomNo = r.roomNo
         GROUP BY r.hotelNo, r.type) AS t
  JOIN (SELECT s.hotelno, MAX(num_bookings) AS max_bookings
          FROM (SELECT r.hotelno, r.type, count(*) AS num_bookings
                  FROM Booking AS b
                  JOIN Room AS r ON b.hotelNo = r.hotelno AND b.roomNo = r.roomNo
                 GROUP BY r.hotelNo, r.type
               ) AS s
         GROUP BY s.hotelno) AS m
    ON t.hotelno = m.hotelno AND t.num_bookings = m.max_bookings;
```

If your DBMS supports WITH clauses, you can write that more succinctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for popularity, you would need to take into account the Booking table.  Add the Booking table to your FROM statement, link on hotelNo and roomNo and do a count on the Booking table.  This should give you the counts you want.

Edit:
Here is some sample code for you (tested):

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Hotel.hotelName, dbo.Room.type, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM dbo.Booking INNER JOIN
dbo.Room ON dbo.Booking.roomNo = dbo.Room.roomNo AND dbo.Booking.hotelNo = dbo.Room.hotelNo 
INNER JOIN dbo.Hotel ON dbo.Room.hotelNo = dbo.Hotel.hotelNo
GROUP BY dbo.Hotel.hotelName, dbo.Room.type
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to use an inner query to get this one working:

```
SELECT dbo.Hotel.hotelName, pop.type, pop.Count
FROM dbo.Hotel
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT TOP 1 dbo.Hotel.hotelNo, dbo.Room.type, COUNT(*) AS Count
        FROM dbo.Hotel
            INNER JOIN dbo.Room ON dbo.Room.hotelNo = dbo.Hotel.hotelNo
            INNER JOIN dbo.Booking ON dbo.Booking.roomNo = dbo.Room.roomNo AND dbo.Booking.hotelNo = dbo.Hotel.hotelNo
        GROUP BY dbo.Hotel.hotelNo, dbo.Room.type
        ORDER BY Count DESC, dbo.Room.type
    ) AS pop ON pop.hotelNo = dbo.Hotel.HotelNo
ORDER BY dbo.Hotel.hotelName
```